# TargetFrameworkVersion v7.0 could not be converted to an Android API level. Xamarin.Forms (Portable)

Tags: debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-sdk-tools

I have created new Xamarin.Forms (Portable) application and tried to build but I am getting the error

```
TargetFrameworkVersion v7.0 could not be converted to an Android API level. Xamarin.Forms (Portable)
```

Please check the attached screenshot.
[image: Please check the attached image]
Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: Do you have these Andorid APIs installed in your SDK Manager? (i.e. Screenshot shows API 19 needs to be installed. Your error says API 24 needs to be installed)

Comment: Yes, I have all the APIs installed on my machine. and now I am reinstalling Visual Studio with Xamarin. API: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2083693/0da018ba0ed148b98bdf7428b1aa1b2e

Comment: Is the Android SDK in your `Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android` pointing to the `e:/` one?

Comment: Yes, Actually everything was working perfectly and then I have updated Xamarin and got so many errors. One of them is Toolbar error.

Comment: reinstallation is not the solution, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved now. I have just formatted my Windows 8.1 and reinstalled everything. I have reinstalled `Windows 8.1` and `Visual Studio 2015 Update 2` and try to rebuild the application and It's working.

I am not sure about the other solution. Maybe there are some other solutions to resolve this issue.

Thank You.