# is it possible to change the bottom border of entry in Xamarin.Forms (Portable)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, styles, xamarin.forms

I want to change the border colour of Editor and Entry in the simplest way, I don't want to create any custom renderer.

Is it possible using Style.xml?

Thank You.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change this from the Android project without custom renderer.

There is already a style file with a theme that you can use to modify this specific property.

This is the line you'd need to add/update with the color you want to use for your Entry.

`<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_text_color</item>`

Note: Be aware that this will change the color on all the others Entries/TextBoxes in your app since this is a global change.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I can't check it because I am getting an [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765177/targetframeworkversion-v7-0-could-not-be-converted-to-an-android-api-level-xama) while debugging an application.

Comment: This is working only if Entry is not focused. I want to change colour also when entry is focused.

Comment: I have tried to change `<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>` but the caret color also changed.

Answer (score 0):

Create xml files with different stroke color in android project, from XAML send background color value through trigger and you find those values in OnElementPropertyChanged in your android renderer then switch the xml how you want.